# FIlter by enum field in Kendo Grid

Tags: enums, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid, odata, filtering

I'm using the grid in Kendo UI to display a list of entities. One of the properties in the entity is an Enum. I am populating the grid from an MVC 5 application using OData v4 by calling an OData controller. The OData library used is Microsoft.AspNet.Odata v5.6. This is how the grid data source is defined:

```
type: "odata-v4",
transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/odata/Groups/",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
```

and the controller action is as simple as

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery(PageSize = 20)]
public IQueryable<Group> GetGroups()
{
    return _GroupService.GetGroups();
}
```

The Group entity is defined as

```
public class Group
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.BusinessEntitiesResources))]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.BusinessEntitiesResources))]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public EnumDepositMethod? DepositMethod { get; set; }
}
```

Now, filtering by the DepositMethod column does not work. The error message is about being unable to compare values of type enum and string. Here's the payload sent to the server:

```
http://localhost:49680/odata/Groups?format=json&top=20&filter=DepositMethod+eq+DebitCard&count=true
```

The query string generated by the kendo grid cannot be changed as far as I know so there's no way to prefix the value sent to the server with the fully qualified name of the enum. Is there a way to make OData interpret the value as an enum on the server side or to make the grid send the "filter by" value correctly prefixed to the server?

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

Just found there is a way to make the OData URI parser less strict when interpreting values who are enums. A call to EnableEnumPrefixFree on the configuration will make the parser attempt to parse the value and match it to one of the enum's members. The OData configuration now looks like:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); //This has to be called before the following OData mapping and before the WebApi mapping
    config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", GetEdmModel());
    config.EnableEnumPrefixFree(enumPrefixFree: true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to change the filter generated by the grid within the [dataSource.transport.parameterMap](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) function.
A work around I have used is a regex replace within the parameterMap function on the kendo datasource object. See below for example.

```
            parameterMap: function (data,operation) {
            if (operation == "read") {
                var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(data);
                if (paramMap.$filter) {
                    paramMap.$filter = paramMap.$filter.replace(/Level\s+(.+)\s+'(.+)'/, "Level $1 System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel'$2'");
                }
                return paramMap;
            }
```